# Import data from excel to oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I'm trying to import data from excel to Oracle SQL. I keep getting an error

Data is not compatible with column definition or is not available for a not nullable column.
 and there are yellow Triangle in column 1
COLUMN 1 is EmployeeID. i just added number like 1, 2 ,3 . 
Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Yes

Show us your data. Show us the table DDL. And show us the picture of SQL Developer showing the errors.

[image]

Here, the EMPLOYEE_ID column is defined as a number, and you have rows in the Excel file that will fail because their values can't be casted as numbers.

If you look down at HIRE_DATE, there's no date format applied so we can take your strings and insert them as dates into the Oracle field

Observe the type, size definitions for the data - then observe the data in the preview window, and see what's not simpatico.

You may have to change your table definition to match.

I talk about this in more detail with a complete scneario [on my blog](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/12/sql-developer-4-1-easier-excel-imports/).

If you prefer YouTube, here's a [30 minute video overview](https://youtu.be/6IZDyxLD49U).

Comment: Fixed IT But now im trying to run A query Select USERINSC521SP18_EAA52.Employee.EmployeeID, USERINSC521SP18_EAA52.Employee.EmployeeFirstName, USERINSC521SP18_EAA52.Employee.EmployeeLastName,
USERINSC521SP18_EAA52.EmployeeEmail.EmployeeEmail, USERINSC521SP18_EAA52.EmployeePhone.EmployeePhone from USERINSC521SP18_EAA52.Employee,
USERINSC521SP18_EAA52.EmployeeEmail,USERINSC521SP18_EAA52.EmployeePhone Where USERINSC521SP18_EAA52.Employee.EmployeeID = USERINSC521SP18_EAA52.EmployeeEmail.EmployeeEmail =
USERINSC521SP18_EAA52.EmployeePhone.EmployeePhone; error SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Fixed it how? Also, SQLDev where show you in your code where the problem is.

Comment: Will show.. https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2018/02/whats-wrong-with-my-code-we-try-to-help-you/